# How can I split my query result in 2 arrays?

Tags: php, wp-query, array

I have made a query which gives me 8 results. I need to show these in 2 columns of 4 items.

This is my query :

```
         $args = array(
                  'post_type' => 'event',
                  'meta_key' => 'date',
                  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                  'order' => 'ASC',
                  'posts_per_page' => 8,
                  'meta_query' => array(
                      'key'       => 'date',
                      'value'     => date('Y-m-d',strtotime("today")),
                      'compare'   => '>=',
                      'type'      => 'DATE'
                   ),
                );

        $events = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I tried using array_splice. Example :

```
        $firstCol = array_slice($events, 0, 4, true);
        $secondCol = array_slice($events, 4, true);
```

But this does not seem to work. How can I get 2 arrays from my result?

Comment: `WP_Query` does return an `object`. The posts `array` you'll find in the `$posts` property. So `$events->posts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to split the array, you can just close the first div once you've counted up to four elements of the array.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => 'date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key'       => 'date',
        'value'     => date('Y-m-d',strtotime("today")),
        'compare'   => '>=',
        'type'      => 'DATE'
    ),
);

$events = new WP_Query( $args ); 
$count  = 1;

if ( $events->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div class="column-1">
    <?php while ( $events->have_posts() ) : $events->the_post();
        // YOUR CONTENT
if ( $count == 4 ) { ?>
    </div>
    <div class="column-2">
<?php }

        $count++;
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
?>
</div>
```

Comment: All WP query objects also have a built-in counter, `$events->current_post`.

Comment: Thx both. I used this solution with $events->current_post for post count.

Comment: @milo, I've never used in the built-in counter before. Would start from now on

Answer (score 0):

if i realy understand your question, put the array in a loop and use a variable as counter

```
$count=0; 
$firstCol=array(); 
$secondCol=array(); 
foreach($events as $event) {
   $count++;
   if($count <= 4 ) {
     array_push($firstCol, $event);
   }
   else {
     array_push($secondCol, $event);
   }
}
```

Comment: I will try this. I was hoping for a "nicer" solution tho.